# How to revoke an Oauth2 refresh token as a Drupal admin?

Tags: users, authentication-authorization

I am currently working on an app that acts as a mobile client for a service of ours that is built on Drupal 7. Currently I use access tokens and refresh tokens via the Oauth2_server module as a means of authentication for activating certain REST functionality. If it helps in any way, I use the password grant-type for the credential flow. It's username and password in, access token and refresh token out.

My main concern is that if a user has his/her phone stolen, the thief may exploit the refresh token (lifespan of 14 days) still inside the app to remain authenticated in perpetuity and commit identity theft. I'm looking for a way to revoke/blacklist this refresh token should the user contact support to minimize the damage.